# iOS App crash and exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: video, memory, crash, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am developing Titanium iOS Module for Trim the Video in certain range and also completed that, Its working fine,
But the app is getting crashed some times while click on Trim Button,

I am just doing the below process at the time of Trim button click,

1. Deleting the existing .mov file in the NSTempDirectory,
2. Exporting an AVAsset into the same path using AVAssetExportSession

   self.exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]
                                 initWithAsset:anAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];

It works few times, But not working often, 
*Application gets crash with the below log in iOS Simulator,*

```
[DEBUG] :  [ioslib] [ios-sim]
[DEBUG] Session did end with error (null)
[DEBUG] :  [ioslib] [ios-sim] 
[DEBUG] Removing named pipe at `/var/folders/0k/yjm3h6ts0z1bdbr8hvn_h1h00000gq/T//ios-sim-stderr->pipe-1460036674'
[DEBUG] :  [ioslib] [ios-sim] 
[DEBUG] Removing named pipe at `/var/folders/0k/yjm3h6ts0z1bdbr8hvn_h1h00000gq/T//ios-sim-stdout-pipe-1460036674'
[DEBUG] :  [ioslib] [ios-sim] Exited with code: 0
```

- Below crash log is while run in iOS device 5S

  Apr  5 16:47:22 s-iPhone-4-1 ReportCrash[360] : ReportCrash acting against PID 357
  Apr  5 16:47:23 s-iPhone-4-1 ReportCrash[360] : Formulating crash report for process AppName[357]
  Apr  5 16:47:23 s-iPhone-4-1 com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.xxx.xxxx[0xae94][357]) : (UIKitApplication:com.xxxx.xxx[0xae94]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
  Apr  5 16:47:23 s-iPhone-4-1 backboardd[28] : Application 'UIKitApplication:com.xxx.xxx[0xae94]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11

Can anyone suggest me the solution, Also let me know if you need anything else.

Thanks in advance

Comment: so what module do you use? Link to github? Have you raised an issue there?

Comment: @Rene Pot, Thanks for your quick answer, I have developed my own module by referencing with this [git hub iOS App](https://github.com/andrei200287/SAVideoRangeSlider)

Answer (score 2):

I have found an error and fixed,

Its happened because of ***removeItemAtURL*** , i just replaced that with ***removeItemAtPath***

```
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    //[fm removeItemAtURL:url error:&err]; // This causes crash
    [fm removeItemAtPath:url.path error:&err];
```